# Asp.net Mvc c# dynamic Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have one application with multi-database login I want to use dynamic session where I can save the user name and his connection string then I could realize session data for the special one in the case log off and also to void sometimes mixed between session data values in saving user data as sometimes when I save data for example for database 1 I find it saved in another database while another user is login for the second one 
my trial is

```
                    List<String> ConnectionSessions = new List<string>();
                    List<String> usernamevalue= new List<string>();

                    ConnectionSessions.Add(query[0].ConnString);
                    usernamevalue.Add(x.Split('-').First());


                    foreach (string section in ConnectionSessions)
                    {
                        foreach (var uname in  usernamevalue)
                        {
                            Session[uname] = section;

                        }
                    }
```

My question how can I call this section and use it is valued in different controles and is my idea right as i know each user has his own session

Comment: I do not understand the scenario.  Please add concrete examples of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I have multi database with one single application for example first user login  then I saved his data session and so the others users from different databases each one go through his application depend on session value sometimes I got error that user doesnt related to database that means May be session mixed between users database mixed or lost it so I need to save all connection string in session array and depend on user name I will get the connection in all pages then I need to know how will loop in each control to set connection depends on username I use asp.net mvc c# dbcontext